# Spring bean injection problem in Flowable service task

Tags: java, spring, bpmn, flowable

I have a question about spring bean injection in service tasks of Flowable, why only this kind of injection with a static modifier worked, and what is the logic of it?

I must inject a spring bean in a Flowable java service task, and I tested some different kind of injection Field, constructor, and setter injection, eventually setter injection with static modifier worked for me like this :

```java
public class GetCurrentUserDlg implements JavaDelegate {

    private static PersonService personService;

    @Autowired
    public void setPersonService(PersonService personService) {
        this.personService = personService;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) {
        personService.getCurrentUser();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I can not answer your question, the following works fine for me:

```
public class SomeDelegate implements JavaDelegate {

    @Autowired
    private SomeBean bean;

    @Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) {
        System.out.println(this.bean);
    }
}
```

The class is then used in the process via `flowable:class="packages.SomeDelegate"`

But, be aware, that you may have problems with autowiring dependencies in the `SomeBean` bean. This dependencies are not injected when using the `flowable:class` attribute. In order for this to work you have to make the `SomeDelegate` a actual bean itself (e.g. via `@Service`) and use it in your process definition via `flowable:delegateExpression="${someDelegate}"`

Example:

```
@Service("someDelegate")
public class SomeDelegate implements JavaDelegate {
...
```

and

```
<serviceTask id="doSomething" name="Do Something" flowable:delegateExpression="${someDelegate}"/>
```

Comment: If the answer was part of the solution would you mind to accept the answer for further references

Comment: Thanks for your response 
Actually I changed my approach, I made JavaDelegate class as a Spring bean, also I used ‘activiti:delegateExpression’ tag in BPMN

I actually do not understand why setter injection in static field only work in the previous approach

Comment: When using `flowable:class` then Flowable will instantiate the class. This means that you can't use Spring Dependency autowiring in those classes. The reply from Matte is the way to go when you want to use Spring Beans

Answer (score 0):

It should work like this:

```java
@Component
public class GetCurrentUserDlg implements JavaDelegate {

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) {
        personService.getCurrentUser();
    }
}

@Component
public class PersonService {
   // its methods
}
```