# Unknown property used in expression when using Java Delegate with Delegate Expression in BPMN

Tags: delegates, flowable

Is anyone also having problem when using java delegate task in service task with delegate expression?
It is ok when placing into class with "org.flowable.DelegateExpressionBean"

**Error Message**

> Forwarding to error page from request [/app/rest/process-instances] due to exception [Unknown property used in expression: ${delegateExpressionBean}]

**Java Class**

```
package org.flowable;

@Component
public class DelegateExpressionBean implements JavaDelegate {
    @Autowired
    ExternalService externalService;
    @Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution delegateExecution) {
       ...
       externalService.call();
    }
```

**BPMN XML**

> <serviceTask id="DelegateExpressionBean" name="Delegate Expression Bean" flowable:delegateExpression="${delegateExpressionBean}">

Answer (score 0):

I think this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63389251/2412627

If you are still having trouble, try to use your own package structure instead of reusing `org.flowable`.